# Get only the filename from s3 using s3hook

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, airflow

I'm creating the below class that is based off the s3CopyObjectOperator, but I have to copy all the files from an s3 directory and save to another directory, then delete the files.

But I need the file names from the directory I'm copying from. So lets say the Copy Source is:

```
my_bucket/folder1/folder2/my_unique_filename.csv
```

I need the new key to be:

```
my_bucket/new_folder1/my_unique_filename.csv
```

So I suppose my question is how can I get only the filenames from the directory so I can use it for my new directory? If the prefix didn't include the directory as well that would have worked.

```
def execute(self, context):

    s3 = S3Hook(self.aws_conn_id)
    s3_conn = s3.get_conn()

    keys = s3.list_keys(bucket_name=self.partition.bucket, prefix=self.partition.key_prefix)


    # copy the files from the bucket
    for key in keys:
        logging.info(f'key :{key}')

        s3_conn.copy_object(Bucket=self.partition.bucket, Key=f'{self.new_key}',
                            CopySource={
                                'Bucket': self.partition.bucket,
                                'Key': key
                                }, 
                                ContentEncoding='csv')

        logging.info(f"self.new_key {self.new_key}")
        s3.delete_objects(self.partition.bucket, key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 is an object store and the "path" is really part of the name. You can think of it as a prefix to the base file name.

Assuming you have the destination prefix you want to append to the filename, you can build the destination key for each s3 key you found.

```
def execute(self, context):

    s3 = S3Hook(self.aws_conn_id)
    s3_conn = s3.get_conn()

    keys = s3.list_keys(bucket_name=self.partition.bucket, prefix=self.partition.key_prefix)

    for key in keys:
        # prefix should be equal to self.partition.key_prefix 
        prefix, filename = os.path.split(key)
        
        dest_key = f'{self.dest_prefix}/{filename}'

        logging.info(f'Copying: {key} to {dest_key}')
        s3_conn.copy_object(
            Bucket=self.partition.bucket,
            Key=f'{dest_key}',
            CopySource={
                'Bucket': self.partition.bucket,
                'Key': key
            },
            ContentEncoding='csv'
        )

        logging.info(f'Deleting: {key}')
        s3.delete_objects(self.partition.bucket, key)
```